# Authentication and Secure Loopback APIs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback, google-api-nodejs-client

I created a loopback api ('http://localhost:8100/api/insertsubmitorder/insertOrders') . this api is not Secure . Can we Secure and Authenticate this API using OAuth2 or Other . I go through the looback docs for Authentication http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html#preparing-access-control-models .

but i can not get  the soluition. Please tell me how can i add Security my loopback APIs.

Comment: what errors did you get? those are official documentation and you couldnt get it to work? be more specific.

Comment: thanks , i am following the docs steps . i tell you what i have do till now with Docs steps-  1. I create a authentication.js file and Create a User.js and User.json file with 'bash' user builtin model.

Comment: can you clarify the docs Procedure , i think i missed some steps . Please guid me

Answer (score 0):

If you have a user-database with already existing users, I'd suggest writing a custom login with LoopBacks built in user-functionality. Otherwise, just create a user and do a login-post to the /login-endpoint. This will return an accesstoken (and also the user object if you wish to include it) which you can use against the endpoints for validation. The validation is setup through the ACL in the models json-objects.

Comment: thanks,one question . is it used oAuth ? or  can we Create a Node server only for Aunthecation ?

Comment: Easy for me to say to read through https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/OAuth-2.0.html but it is a component you can add. We use oauth to get an access-token from a remote service which we then tell Loopback if it exists that the user is trustworthy. Would probably be easier to use the component in the link, though.